# Simple Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to integrate a friends website (photographer) with Facebook. I've been trying to find the answer in the Facebook Developers guide, but it doesn't seem clear to me.

What would I need if:

- I want to have a like button per photo album he has
- I want to publish his news that he enters in my cms to his facebook wall

Do I need an application? Or can I accomplish this with plugins?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are these albums on the same page? i.e. multiple LIKE buttons will be present on the same page?

Comment: @ifaour no these albums are not on the same page. one time it's the link gallery.php?id=23 and the other time it's gallery.php?id=24. I think it's OK now for the like button. Only thing that bothering me is that in the meta tags i set a picture. When people like the album the picture isn't shown on the Facebookwall. When they post a comment with it the picture is shown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the like button can [just be added by inserting a code snipped](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

facebook will take care of the rest.

if you however want to do more with your liked pages like send updates and have statistics, you need to [register an app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas) and supply the app id as meta tag in your website. the [open graph notation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) is used.

to publish news post you can obtain a permament token and publish using the graph api, but there are also [alternative and probably easier methods](http://www.facebook.com/notes/blogging-with-beth/how-to-publish-your-blog-posts-to-facebook-automatically/245596473016)

Comment: Hi, i've used the alernative mode for publishing the blog. The plugin for the like button. I just didn't have any overview anymore. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it simple and be able to accomplish these with just plugins... FB's documentation is quite rich:

In here it explains how to add the like button:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

And this to post to his wall:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream

Comment: Hi, i've used the like plugin. But I can't seem to figure out what the live-stream plugin does. No real documentation on the facebook site. For now this should do but I'll get into the documentation en code for better integration.